# ls -R fails to watch files recursively (with entr)

Tags: command-line, bash

`entr` is a linux package that takes a watch command and then runs another command upon seeing any file modifications. Examples:

http://eradman.com/entrproject/

```
# Rebuild project if sources change
$ ls | entr make

# Rebuild project and run tests if the build was successful
$ ls | entr -s 'make && make test'
```

I am trying to watch from my project root and (re)run bats, a bash test runner, on any file change.

```
~/cp/projectName$ ls -R | entr ./node_modules/bats/bin/bats -r ./helpers/tests
```

- The only file modifications that trigger a re-run are ones in the project root.
- Changes to files in /helpers and /helpers/tests are both ignored
- I have tried not using the -R (recursive) flag. There is no change to the watcher behavior.

Is there a better way to get `entr` to watch for any nested file change in the subfolder tree?

I could open multiple terminals to watch the sub-folders. This would harm my workflow as screen space is insufficient for all of them; I'd have to switch active terminal tabs (Lubuntu 20.04).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `ls` doesn't watch anything. `entr` is apparently taking in paths as input and watching them; `ls` merely one tool to print those paths. It so happens that for the current directory, filenames are equivalent to paths.

Second, if `entr` really is expecting paths, `ls -R` output will mostly be gibberish for it, because it prints the directory name as a heading line and then the filenames beneath it, so the paths aren't available for `entr`. You should use `find`, instead:

```
find | entr ...
```